# Cookies with iframe: SameSite = None not working on server

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, iframe, samesite

I am working on an ASPX page which works with iFrame. After chrome v80 upgrade the site was not working.
I made below changes in ASP.NET .cs page to set samesite attribute.

Now the fix is working on my DEV and UAT servers. But it still failing in PROD servers.
Below are the screen shot of cookies from UAT and PROD. Whereas the same code is deployed on both the servers.

**Please provide possible root cause, looks like cookies attribute is getting overwrite.**

Code:

```
HttpCookie cookie = Cookie.CreateCookie(a_sAuthenticationGuid, a_objContext, uData.SUID);
cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
cookie.Secure = true;
```

PROD:
[image: PROD Cookies snapshot][PROD Cookies snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HW2v.jpg)

UAT:
[image: UAT Cookies snapshot][UAT Cookies snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUqNY.jpg)

Comment: Did you find a solution to that?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved via doing below.
You can check the prod server updates and mainly update .NetFramework with the latest patches.

Comment: It was better to write this as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the samesite setting in chrome to get this resolved and after updating chrome setting for samesite, its working.
search for samesite on cookies://flags